# Блокировка копирования файлов с рабочего стола

Tags: c#

Подскажите, можно ли какими-нибудь способами запретить копирование файлов с рабочего стола?

Comment: Этот вопрос к программированию не относится. Это администрирование ОС скорее. Групповая политика винды к примеру.

Comment: @Bulson, Я сначала подумал что может быть есть альтернатива при использование какой-нибудь `WinApi` функции, сделать что-то типо если пользователь копирует файл блокировать его. Но если так и не получиться сделать буду копать.

Comment: Эээ... А для чего вам нужно такое откровенно враждебное по отношению к пользователю поведение?

Comment: @VladD, Хехе... В целях защиты от поведения других программ, которые могут сделать несанкционированное копирование данных в системе.

Comment: @ArteS: Эээ, не санкционированное **кем**? Вашим кодом или юзером?

Comment: @ArteS: На своей машине юзер царь и бог. Захочет — зайдёт с администраторскими правами, или запустит вашу программу в виртуалке или под отладчиком.

Comment: @VladD, Я пытался намекнуть что пользователь может запустить случайно левый `.exe`файл, который сможет скопировать секретные данные с определенного места, и что бы это избежать, я хотел узнать можно ли запретить копирования файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Если копирование не осуществляется непосредственное через твою программу, то, мне кажется, что не как.

Если копирование осуществляется через твою программу, то проверяй местоположения файла перед копированием и если он на рабочем столе, то не копируй.